# Блокировать окно с причинами закрытия, если кончились голоса на закрытие

Tags: предложение, закрытие-вопросов

Столкнулся с пренеприятнейшей `:)` ситуацией: кончились суточные голоса на закрытие. Однако вопросы, для которых имеет смысл инициировать процедуру закрытия, совсем не хотят кончаться. И вот, на таком вопросе я жму ссылку `закрыть` под телом вопроса. Открывается ожидаемое окно (на скриншоте я уже выбрал один из пунктов):

> [image: возвращайтесь, мы вас ждём]

Выбор пунктов активен, кнопка <kbd>Голосовать за закрытие</kbd> тоже. Хуже того, я выбрал в итоге "не по теме" → "другое" и даже написал текст на пару строк. Но после нажатия кнопки получил ожидаемый результат:

> [image: лимит достигнут]

"Надо было смотреть на заголовок или на число, рядом с текстом `голосов осталось`" - скажете вы. Но кто ж на них смотрит, когда всё остальные пункты доступны?! В общем, время было потеряно зря. Пришлось идти в чат и просить других SOучастников проявить гражданскую позицию по вопросу.

Отсюда мораль, т.е. предложение:

> Заблокировать выбор пунктов, кнопку голосования, поле ввода собственной причины, а то и вовсе отображение данного баннера, если кол-во голосов на текущий момент равно нулю.

Comment: [meta-tag:статус-так-задумано] :)

Comment: @Grundy давайте раздумаем тогда!