# Новое всплывающее окно закрытия вопросов не влезает в экран

Tags: дефект, дизайн, закрытие-вопросов

Недавно поменяли pop-up закрытия вопроса.  Новый вариант слишком
огромный.  Приходится его возить по экрану, чтобы что-то найти.  См.
скриншоты.  Первый pop-up ещё куда ни шло, хотя и касается дна.
Второй — ни в какие ворота.

[image: Первый попап]

[image: Второй попап]

Comment: Это на каком экране и с каким разрешением такое? О_о

Comment: Сам экран 1366 × 768, вьюпорт 1299 × 649.  Вполне типичные характеристики экрана ноутбука, см. [статистику](https://www.w3schools.com/browsers/browsers_display.asp).  Не у всех же эта ваша ре́тина.

Comment: У меня уже много лет 1920x1080 на вполне обычном Асусе)

Comment: А может завалялся скрин того, как этот попап раньше выглядел?

Comment: Вряд ли.  Разве что в интернете порыться.  Началось не более пары недель назад, как мне кажется.  Возможно, изменили шрифты или вёрстку.

Comment: Старые окошки можно подсмотреть [тут](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/9903/) и [тут](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4099/). Я разницы в размерах не заметил с точки зрения взгляда обывателя с FullHD монитором.

Comment: Не знаю мне кажется или вложенность возросла, из-за этого надо 3 влика, а не 2 для репорта англоязычного вопроса.